# UIMA Ruta: JCas cannot be initialized/Script cannot be found

Tags: java, uima, ruta, uimafit

I try to integrate a UIMA Ruta script (`Main.ruta`) in an uimaFIT-pipeline (in`Main.java`) but the script cannot be found.
This is my project structure:

```
uima-ruta-maven-test-project/src/main/Main.java
uima-ruta-maven-test-project/script/ruta/Main.ruta
uima-ruta-maven-test-project/descriptor/ruta/MainEngine.xml
```

Here is my code to create the `AnalysisEngineDescription`:

```
File file = new File("descriptor/ruta/MainEngine.xml");

AnalysisEngineDescription rutaScript = AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngineDescriptionFromPath(
                    file.getPath(),
                    RutaEngine.PARAM_SCRIPT_PATHS, "script",
                    RutaEngine.PARAM_MAIN_SCRIPT, "Main.ruta");
```

And this is my console output:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.
org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException: Initialization of annotator class "org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine" failed.  (Descriptor: file:/D:/Programming/MA/uima-ruta-maven-test-project/descriptor/ruta/MainEngine.xml)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:260)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:173)
    at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94)
    at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62)
    at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:289)
    at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:417)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.setup(ASB_impl.java:256)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initASB(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:435)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAggregateAnalysisEngine(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:379)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:192)
    at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94)
    at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62)
    at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:289)
    at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:341)
    at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:458)
    at org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:178)
    at Main.main(Main.java:52)
Caused by: org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initialize(RutaEngine.java:579)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.lambda$callInitializeMethod$2(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:612)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.withContexts(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:653)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.callInitializeMethod(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:612)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:252)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeScript(RutaEngine.java:857)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initialize(RutaEngine.java:576)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Script [Main.ruta] cannot be found at [script;D:\Programming\MA\uima-ruta-maven-test-project] or classpath with extension .ruta
    ... 22 more
```

The last line of my console output seems to show the error. `Main.ruta` is searched in the path `[script;D:\Programming\MA\uima-ruta-maven-test-project]` which obviously doesn't exist because it is an invalid path. What I'm thinking is that the method `createEngineDescriptionFromPath` should append the `"script"` folder to the project path. But instead it prepends it.

Can someone help me with this, please?

**EDIT**

I have found [this](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae.basic) link to the documentation where the usage of the parameters `mainScript` and `scriptPaths` is explained. The paths have to be written with "." instead of "/".

I changed my code as follows:

```
AnalysisEngineDescription rutaScript = AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngineDescriptionFromPath(
                    file.getPath(),
                    RutaEngine.PARAM_SCRIPT_PATHS, "script.ruta",
                    RutaEngine.PARAM_MAIN_SCRIPT, "script.ruta.Main");
```

But now I am getting this console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.uima.cas.CASRuntimeException: The JCas cannot be initialized.  The following errors occurred: 
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.AnyLine", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/uima/ruta-typesystem/2.7.0/ruta-typesystem-2.7.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/AnyLine.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.EmptyLine", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/uima/ruta-typesystem/2.7.0/ruta-typesystem-2.7.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/EmptyLine.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.WSLine", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/uima/ruta-typesystem/2.7.0/ruta-typesystem-2.7.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/WSLine.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
...
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSClassRegistry.reportErrors(FSClassRegistry.java:1284)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSClassRegistry.loadJCasForTSandClassLoader(FSClassRegistry.java:400)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSClassRegistry.getGeneratorsForClassLoader(FSClassRegistry.java:1320)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.TypeSystemImpl.getGeneratorsForClassLoader(TypeSystemImpl.java:2924)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.TypeSystemImpl.commit(TypeSystemImpl.java:1442)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.CASImpl.commitTypeSystem(CASImpl.java:1822)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasCreationUtils.doCreateCas(CasCreationUtils.java:620)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasCreationUtils.createCas(CasCreationUtils.java:292)
at org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:181)
at Main.main(Main.java:52)
```

It seems like the Ruta types cannot be initialized. I have UIMA Ruta version 2.7.0 and DKPro 2.0.0 in my pom.xml.

Comment: "UIMA version 3 or later JCas required". What version of UIMA framework do you use?

Comment: I have the UIMA Runtime 3.1.0, UIMA Ruta Workbench 2.7.0 and UIMA Tools 3.1.0 installed in Eclipse. Also, I have uimaj-core (3.1.0), ruta-core (2.7.0), ruta-typesystem (2.7.0) and dkpro-core-asl (2.0.0) in my pom.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like UIMA Ruta 2 doesn't fit together well with UIMA v3 and other libraries that rely on it (uimaFit, DKPro in this case).

I got it to work in my case with the following versions: DKPro 1.11.0, UIMA 2.10.4, UIMA Ruta 2.7.0 and uimaFit 2.4.0 (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569586/uima-ruta-uimafit-and-dkpro-which-versions-work-together)).

[UIMA Ruta 3](https://uima.apache.org/news.html#09%20Dec%202019) was recently released. I guess this version will work together better with UIMA v3.