# UIMA Ruta, uimaFIT and DKPro: Which versions work together?

Tags: eclipse, uima, ruta, dkpro-core, uimafit

In the [GSCL 2013 Ruta tutorial](https://github.com/dkpro/dkpro-tutorials/tree/master/GSCL2013/trunk/gscl2013-ruta) the versions of the components in the pom.xml are:

```
uimaj-core: 2.4.2
DKPro components: 1.5.0
ruta-core: 2.1.0
```

Now, I incremented the version numbers incrementally and found that version 1.8.0 of the DKPro components introduces the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.uima.cas.text.AnnotationIndex.withSnapshotIterators()Lorg/apache/uima/cas/FSIndex;
    at org.apache.uima.fit.util.FSCollectionFactory$AnnotationIndexAdapter.iterator(FSCollectionFactory.java:821)
    at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.SegmenterBase.process(SegmenterBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:378)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:298)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:568)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:410)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:343)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:267)
    at org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:150)
    at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.tutorial.gscl2013.ruta.WhatAliceDoesExample.main(WhatAliceDoesExample.java:38)
```

In the last days I faced other version problems (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507396/uima-ruta-editor-could-not-be-initialized)) with these components.
Can someone tell me what the most current versions of these components are that work together? Or maybe someone can give me his/her versions that he/she currently works with? I am also interested in the used eclipse version. Thank you very much. I am stuck with this issue for some time now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Irrespective which version of DKPro Core or Ruta you use, it is a good idea to use a recent UIMA and uimaFIT version.

Note that there was an incompatible change with UIMA v3+ (uimaFIT v3+). E.g. DKPro Core 2.0.0 works with these new versions, but DKPro Core 1.x works only with UIMA v2 and uimaFIT v2. Presently (2019-10-26), there is no Ruta version compatible with UIMA v3.

Check the POM files of DKPro Core and Ruta which versions of UIMA and uimaFIT they use.

[DKPro Core 2.0.0](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.dkpro.core/dkpro-core/2.0.0/pom) ->

```
<uima.version>3.1.0</uima.version>
<uimafit.version>3.0.0</uimafit.version>
```

[DKPro Core 1.11.0](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.dkpro.core/dkpro-core/1.11.0/pom) (note change in group ID in this version) ->

```
<uima.version>2.10.3</uima.version>
<uimafit.version>2.4.0</uimafit.version>
```

[DKPro Core 1.10.0](https://search.maven.org/artifact/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core/1.10.0/pom) ->

```
<uima.version>2.10.2</uima.version>
<uimafit.version>2.4.0</uimafit.version>
```

[DKPro Core 1.8.0](https://search.maven.org/artifact/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core/1.8.0/pom) ->

```
<uima.version>2.8.1</uima.version>
<uimafit.version>2.2.0</uimafit.version>
```

[Ruta 2.7.0](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.uima/ruta-parent/2.7.0/pom)

```
<uimaVersion>2.10.3</uimaVersion>
<uimafit-version>2.4.0</uimafit-version>
```

As for Eclipse: I'd just use the most recent version. If you experience trouble with Ruta in the latest Eclipse versions, best report it on the [UIMA users' mailing](https://uima.apache.org/mail-lists.html) list.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I'm going with DKPro 1.11.0, UIMA 2.10.4, UIMA Ruta 2.7.0 and uimaFIT 2.4.0 with Eclipse Photon because I didn't receive NullPointerExceptions when closing the UIMA Annotation Editor (see this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507396/uima-ruta-editor-could-not-be-initialized)).

Comment: I updated the example project: https://github.com/pkluegl/ruta-examples/tree/master/ruta-german-novel-with-dkpro