# What does this error mean in UIMA Ruta based project?

Tags: uima, ruta

Receiving this call when I run my project it is a fact extraction tool named SalIE on GitHub. Need help on how to fix this error. Seems like a version issue with something but unknown. The below error causes the tool to fail and not work further.

```
Aug 17, 2021 11:34:21 AM org.apache.uima.internal.util.XMLUtils createSaxTransformerFactory(614)
[error] WARNING: SAXTransformerFactory didn't recognize setting attribute http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
[error] Aug 17, 2021 11:34:21 AM org.apache.uima.internal.util.XMLUtils createSaxTransformerFactory(621)
[error] WARNING: SAXTransformerFactory didn't recognize setting attribute http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalStylesheet
[error] Aug 17, 2021 11:34:22 AM de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.io.ResourceCollectionReaderBase scan(422)
```

Comment: Do you have a link to unit test or something similar to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using dkpro.  This is how I call dkpro from my ruta script.  This might help you.  The imports make those annotation types available in the rest of the script.

Oh and be careful about which versions you use together.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569586/uima-ruta-uimafit-and-dkpro-which-versions-work-together)

```
IMPORT PACKAGE de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.lexmorph.type.pos
    FROM desc.type.POS AS pos;
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Lemma
    FROM desc.type.LexicalUnits;
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Token
    FROM desc.type.LexicalUnits_customized;   
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Sentence
FROM desc.type.LexicalUnits_customized;
IMPORT PACKAGE de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.syntax.type.dependency
    FROM desc.type.Dependency AS dep;
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.type.ReadabilityScore
    FROM desc.type.ReadabilityScore;
IMPORT de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.metadata.type.TagsetDescription
    FROM desc.type.metadata;

UIMAFIT org.dkpro.core.opennlp.OpenNlpSegmenter;
UIMAFIT org.dkpro.core.tokit.ParagraphSplitter;
UIMAFIT org.dkpro.core.opennlp.OpenNlpPosTagger;
UIMAFIT org.dkpro.core.corenlp.CoreNlpLemmatizer;
UIMAFIT org.dkpro.core.maltparser.MaltParser;
UIMAFIT org.dkpro.core.readability.ReadabilityAnnotator;

//NLP ANNOTATIONS
uima.tcas.DocumentAnnotation{-CONTAINS(pos.POS)} -> {
    uima.tcas.DocumentAnnotation{-> SETFEATURE("language", "en")};
    EXEC(OpenNlpSegmenter);
    EXEC(ParagraphSplitter);
    EXEC(OpenNlpPosTagger);
    EXEC(CoreNlpLemmatizer);
    EXEC(MaltParser); 
    EXEC(ReadabilityAnnotator);
};
```